# Differences in LAG() function: R vs SQL (Converting R code to SQL)

Tags: sql, r, db2

I have the following table in R:

```
library(dplyr)

   df = structure(list(name = c("John", "John", "John", "Mary", "Mary", 
"Mary", "Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob"), year = c(2001, 
2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003
), var1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"b", "b"), var2 = c("b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"a", "b", "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))


  name year var1 var2
  John 2001    a    b
  John 2002    a    a
  John 2003    a    b
  Mary 2001    b    a
  Mary 2002    a    b
  Mary 2003    b    a
 Alice 2001    a    b
 Alice 2002    b    a
 Alice 2003    a    b
   Bob 2001    b    a
   Bob 2002    b    b
   Bob 2003    b    a
```

I want to answer the following question:

- For each name, when (i.e., which row_num) does var1 change for the first time? Keep the full information for that row so we can see the change in var1_before/var1_after and var2_before/var2_after
- If a name kept its var1 value throughout - return the full information row for the last available year corresponding to that name (along with the row_number)
- The final result will only have 1 row per name

I spent some time and I think was able to do this in R:

```
df %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(
        row_num = row_number(),
        var1_lag = lag(var1),
        var2_lag = lag(var2),
        var1_change = var1 != var1_lag,
        first_year = first(year)  
    ) %>%
    filter(var1_change | row_num == max(row_num)) %>%
    mutate(
        category = ifelse(var1_change, "Var1 Changed", "Var1 Never Changed"),

        year_when_var1_changed = ifelse(var1_change, year, NA),
        var1_before = ifelse(var1_change, var1_lag, var1),
        var1_after = var1,
        var2_before = ifelse(var1_change, var2_lag, var2),
        var2_after = var2
    ) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
    select(name, first_year, category, year_when_var1_changed, var1_before, var1_after, var2_before, var2_after)


  # A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   name [4]
  name  first_year category           year_when_var1_changed var1_before var1_after var2_before var2_after
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>                               <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     
1 John        2001 Var1 Never Changed                     NA a           a          b           b         
2 Mary        2001 Var1 Changed                         2002 b           a          a           b         
3 Alice       2001 Var1 Changed                         2002 a           b          b           a         
4 Bob         2001 Var1 Never Changed                     NA b           b          a           a
```

Now, I am trying to do this in SQL (e.g DB2), but I keep getting stuck on how to convert this R code into SQL.

I know how to start - I definitely need to use Lag/Lead functions in a window style, but I can't figure out how to continue:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        year, 
        var1, 
        var2,
        LAG(var1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var1_before,
        LEAD(var1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var1_after,
        LAG(var2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var2_before,
        LEAD(var2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS var2_after,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year ASC) AS row_num
    FROM 
        df
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
    CTE;
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Update using @The Impaler's answer (variable change name):

```
select 
  name as name,
  min(year) over(partition by name) as first_year,
  case when max(v) over(partition by name) > 1 then 'Changed' else 'Not_Changed' end as category,
  year as year_when_var1_changed,
  lag1 as var1_before,
  var1 as var1_after,
  lag2 as var2_before,
  var2 as var2_after
from (
  select y.*, max(v) over(partition by name) as maxv,
    max(rn) over(partition by name) as maxrn
  from (
    select x.*, 
      sum(case when lag1 = var1 then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(partition by name order by year) as v,
      row_number() over(partition by name order by year) as rn
    from (
      select t.*,
        lag(var1) over(partition by name order by year) as lag1,
        lag(var2) over(partition by name order by year) as lag2
      from t
    ) x
  ) y
) z
where maxv > 1 and v = 2 or maxv = 1 and rn = maxrn;
```

Comment: What's database are you using?

Comment: I am using DB2 ... but I am trying to do this with very general SQL functions that could be applied to any database

Comment: Should for John the last yeat be 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
select *
from (
  select y.*, max(v) over(partition by name) as maxv,
    max(rn) over(partition by name) as maxrn
  from (
    select x.*, 
      sum(case when lag1 = var1 then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(partition by name order by year) as v,
      row_number() over(partition by name order by year) as rn
    from (
      select t.*,
        lag(var1) over(partition by name order by year) as lag1,
        lag(var2) over(partition by name order by year) as lag2
      from t
    ) x
  ) y
) z
where maxv > 1 and v = 2 or maxv = 1 and rn = maxrn
```

Result:

```
 NAME   YEAR  VAR1  VAR2  LAG1  LAG2  V  RN  MAXV  MAXRN 
 ------ ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -- --- ----- ----- 
 Alice  2002  b     a     a     b     2  2   3     3     
 Bob    2003  b     a     b     b     1  3   1     3     
 John   2003  a     b     a     a     1  3   1     3     
 Mary   2002  a     b     b     a     2  2   3     3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xV3mC-8s).

The example runs in DB2, but the SQL query is generic, so it should run in most modern databases.

Comment: thank you so much! is it possible to make a new columns with values: var_1_did_not_change, var1_did_change?

Comment: Yes, just add `case when maxv = 1 then 'var_1_did_not_change' else 'var1_did_change' end as notes`. See [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VJFojVeP).

Comment: thank you so much! I changed the variable names in your final answer :)

Comment: select 
  name as name,
  min(year) over(partition by name) as first_year,
  case when max(v) over(partition by name) > 1 then 'Changed' else 'Not_Changed' end as category,
  year as year_when_var1_changed,
  lag1 as var1_before,
  var1 as var1_after,
  lag2 as var2_before,
  var2 as var2_after
from

Comment: (
  select y.*, max(v) over(partition by name) as maxv,
    max(rn) over(partition by name) as maxrn
  from (
    select x.*, 
      sum(case when lag1 = var1 then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(partition by name order by year) as v,
      row_number() over(partition by name order by year) as rn

Comment: from (
      select t.*,
        lag(var1) over(partition by name order by year) as lag1,
        lag(var2) over(partition by name order by year) as lag2
      from t
    ) x
  ) y
) z
where maxv > 1 and v = 2 or maxv = 1 and rn = maxrn;

Comment: Add it to the fiddle as an extra query at the end, and copy the URL here. Not easy to read as a comment.

Comment: I have never used fiddle before. i will try to figure it out... I will post the modifications in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Below tmp adds a prev column and an r column which counts backwards starting at 1 so the last year in any name is 1.  tmp2 selects out the last row for each name as well as any row for which var1 is not equal to the previous var1.  tmp3 numbers the rows that remain as column r2 and then the last select picks out the first row for each name.

```
library (sqldf)

sqldf('

  with tmp as (
    select *, 
      (lag(var1) over (partition by name order by year)) prev1,
      (lag(var2) over (partition by name order by year)) prev2,
      (row_number() over (partition by name order by year desc)) r
    from df
  ),

  tmp2 as (
    select *, case when var1 != prev1 then "change" else "no change" end change
      from tmp 
      where r = 1 or var1 != prev1
  ),

  tmp3 as (
    select *, 
           (row_number() over (partition by name order by year)) r2 
      from tmp2)

  select name, year, var1, var2, prev1, prev2, change
    from tmp3 where r2 = 1
')

##    name year var1 var2 prev1 prev2    change
## 1 Alice 2002    b    a     a     b    change
## 2   Bob 2003    b    a     b     b no change
## 3  John 2003    a    b     a     a no change
## 4  Mary 2002    a    b     b     a    change
```

The above is reasonably generic but it may be possible to reduce it by using database specific code.  For SQLite this shorter code gives the same result. It u ses the fact that with SQLite when min or max is used the other columns are guaranteed to come from the same row.

```
sqldf('

  with tmp as (
    select *, 
      (lag(var1) over (partition by name order by year)) prev1,
      (lag(var2) over (partition by name order by year)) prev2,
      (row_number() over (partition by name order by year desc)) r
    from df)

  select name, min(year) year, var1, var2, prev1, prev2, 
    case when var1 != prev1 then "change" else "no change" end change
  from tmp
  where (var1 != prev1) or (r = 1) 
  group by name')

##    name year var1 var2 prev1 prev2    change
## 1 Alice 2002    b    a     a     b    change
## 2   Bob 2003    b    a     b     b no change
## 3  John 2003    a    b     a     a no change
## 4  Mary 2002    a    b     b     a    change
```

### Update

Added prev2 and change columns.